# SublimeLinter ESLint: Lint Whole Project/Directory Instead of Individual File

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, eslint, sublimelinter

After an hour+ on Google, I can't believe I haven't found any answers or questions to this. I'm using the `SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint` package in Sublime Text 3. Is there a way to force `SublimeLinter` to lint a whole project instead of just one file?

I have a semi-large client-side project with a lot of separate files, and obviously, these files share variables across the `window`. However, by default, `SublimeLinter` only lints a single file, so it throws errors that `'<variable>' is not defined (no-undef)` when another file defines it and `'<variable>' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)` when other files use it.

In my `.eslintrc`, I can set these global variables like this:

```
"globals": {
    "m": true,
    "app": true
},
```

I could also do this in each file, which is arguably good practice anyway:

```
var m = m || {};
var app = app || {};
```

But these methods do not fix the `unused variable` errors.

The best solution I've come up with is to force `SublimeLinter` to lint the entire directory rather than the individual file. I can't figure out a way to do this though.

I tried turning on the `chdir` setting in `SublimeLinter`'s user settings:

```
{
    "user": {
        ...
        "linters": {
            "eslint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "chdir": "${project}"
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

But ^this just sets the `$PWD` when running `eslint`, not the arguments passed to `eslint`.

So is there a way to force `SublimeLinter` to lint an entire directory (or the whole project)? Is there a better solution to this problem that I haven't thought of? Maybe I'm just spoiled by `go fmt`.